# I need a WPF ComboBox control that uses a most recently used list of items

Tags: wpf, combobox

I need a WPF ComboBox control that uses a most recently used list of items. I want to store file paths the user enters in one combobox. In another combobox I want to store any text the user entered. The combobox should allow me to keep track and store of the last twenty items or so

Comment: Where will your most recent items be stored ? File, database, etc. ?

Comment: Registry, database, isolated storage, or anything else. Yet, I do not want to store in .config file.